# How does an accessory drive hydraulic system power a crop duster pump?

Tags: helicopter, hydraulic-system, aerial-application

Aerial agricultural spraying uses pumps, which are usually powered electrically from the starter/generator. Now I have read, that these pumps can also be powered by an accessory drive hydraulic system. How does that work?

Comment: I’m not clear on the level of detail you are looking for in an answer.  At the simplest level an output shaft from the engine that could drive any accessory, (like a generator) would be used instead to power a hydraulic pump.  Are you familiar with how hydraulic systems work?  If your question was a bit more specific you might get some answers...